# Parsing CSV and then Using the Data to Build Highcharts Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I want to create a bar chart visualization **IN JS FIDDLE** that will visualize 'Q1 / 18 (TTM) Annual Guest Value' and 'Days Between 1st and 2nd Visits' for each category of Consumer which is: ['1', '2', .....'29+']. The bar chart should look like this (the legend is covering the 1st category but I'll fix this):

[image]

I assume that the data is present already in a CSV that looks like:

[image]

I have an interface that will allow the user to import a CSV file. It is here:

```js
// The event listener for the file upload 
document.getElementById('txtFileUpload').addEventListener('change', upload, false);
 
// Method that checks that the browser supports the HTML5 File API
function browserSupportFileUpload() {
    var isCompatible = false;
    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
        isCompatible = true;
    }

    return isCompatible;
}

function upload(evt) {
    if (!browserSupportFileUpload()) {
        alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser!');
    } else {
        var data = null;
        var file = evt.target.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(file);
        reader.onload = function(event) {
            var csvData = event.target.result; //alert(csvData);
            var data2 = csvData.split("\n"); //alert(data2);
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < data2.length; ++i) {
                // here's the data row separated by commas
                alert(i+': '+data2[i]);
                // call your ajax and submit this one row
                // now wait for response
                // if not error:
                // advance progress bar, and number converted, etc in modal
                // else:
                // show error message
            }
                    
            if (data2 && data2.length > 0) {
                alert('Imported -' + data2.length + '- rows successfully!');
            } else {
                alert('No data to import!');
            }
        };
        reader.onerror = function() {
            alert('Unable to read ' + file.fileName);
        };
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>File Upload Test</h1>
<p>
    <div id="dvImportSegments" class="fileupload ">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Select the CSV file to upload</legend>
            <input type="file" name="File Upload" id="txtFileUpload" accept=".csv" />
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</p>
```

Then, I am using .get() to bring in the variable csvData (from a function in the above code) and then I will parse it using the function parseCSVData (the function is written below). Then, I will make the bar chart of the data. Here is my code for this part:

```js
$.get(csvData, function (csvFile) { //retrieve csvData from other function above

var data = parseCSVData(csvFile);
  
  
  //create the chart
  
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },
 
  title: {
    text: null,
    align: 'center',
    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11-17', '18-28', '29+'],

    title: {
      text: 'Visits Per Customer (TTM)'
    },
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    gridLineWidth: 0,
   minorGridLineWidth: 0,     
    
    title: {
      text: 'Average Return Rate Overall: 64 Days',
      y: 10
    },
    
    labels: {
      overflow: 'justify'
      
    }
  },
  
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
    pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
      '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.0f} </b></td></tr>',
    footerFormat: '</table>',
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
      }
    }
  },
  legend: {
  
    layout: 'horizontal',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    x: -25,
    y: 5,
    floating: true,
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
   
    shadow: true
    
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Q1 / 18 (TTM) Annual Guest Value',
    //data: 2nd column of CSV file
    color: 'grey',
    // label color
    dataLabels: {
      style: {
        color: 'grey'
       
      }
    }
  }, {
    name: 'Days Between 1st and 2nd Visits',
    //data: 3rd Column of CSV file
    color: 'green',
    // label color
    dataLabels: {
      style: {
        color: 'green'
      }
    }
  }]
})

})
  
  
function parseCSVData (csvFile){

    //empty array for storing the chart data
    var guestvalue_and_visits = []; //2nd and 3rd column extraction
  
    var lines = csvFile.split("\n");
  
    $.each(lines, function (lineNumber, line){
        if(lineNumber != 0) { //skipping header lines
            var fields = line.split(",");
            var a = parseFloat(fields[1]); // this is guest value
            var b = parseFloat(fields[2]); //this is days between visit
            guestvalue_and_visits.push([a , b]);
        }
    })
    return guestvalue_and_visits.reverse();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

My questions are:

What is the right form of the data that I need to parse? Is it var data2 = csvData.split("\n") OR is it var csvData = event.target.result?

Did I bring in the variable csvData (or data2 if this is the right one) in correctly in .get()? I am not an expert in Javascript but I am pretty sure that for instance the variable csvData is local to reader.onload = function(event){} so I would somehow need to access this local variable. How would I bring this correctly into .get()? Would simply writing .get(csvData, function (csvFile){  be okay?

Also, if you look at the 'data' property under 'series', I have left it blank because I do not know how to bring the data from the guestvalue_and_visits variable into the Highcharts code. (I did guestvalue_and_visits.push([a , b] because this is the form Highcharts accepts). I want to extract the 'a' and 'b' part from the data structure and put them in their corresponding 'data' property under 'series'. How would I do this?

Last but not least, bringing everything together how would I allow the interface to FIRST allow the user to upload a CSV file and THEN when it is uploaded, the interface will change to the Highcharts bar chart? Is there some sort of code I need to write to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the right form of the data that I need to parse? Is it var
>   data2 = csvData.split("\n") OR is it var csvData =
>   event.target.result?

In your case I recommend you to separate the categories and series data in your CSV string parser, and return two different series with data included, just like that:

```
var parseCSV = function(csv) {
    var lines = csv.split("\n").map(line => line.split(",")) // split string to lines
    var categories = []
    var series = [{
      name: 'Q1 / 18 (TTM) Annual Guest Value',
      color: 'grey',
      data: [],
      dataLabels: {
        style: {
          color: 'grey'

        }
      }
    }, {
      name: 'Days Between 1st and 2nd Visits',
      color: 'green',
      data: [],
      dataLabels: {
        style: {
          color: 'green'
        }
      }
    }]
        // Parse every line of csv file.
    lines.forEach((line, i) => {
      if (i !== 0) {
        var cat = line[0].slice(1, -1)
        var p1 = parseFloat(line[1])
        var p2 = parseFloat(line[2])

        categories.push(cat)
        series[0].data.push(p1)
        series[1].data.push(p2)
      }
    })
    // return the object with categories and series
    return {
        categories: categories,
      series: series
    }
  }
```

Then just assign the categories, and series:

```
var parsedCSV = parseCSV(csv)

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  xAxis: {
    categories: parsedCSV.categories
  },
  series: parsedCSV.series
})
```

> Did I bring in the variable csvData (or data2 if this is the right one) in correctly in .get()? I am not an expert in Javascript but I am pretty sure that for instance the variable csvData is local to reader.onload = function(event){} so I would somehow need to access this local variable. How would I bring this correctly into .get()? Would simply writing .get(csvData, function (csvFile){ be okay?

I don't see your whole project structure, but yes, the `csvData` and `data2` variables scope is limited only to `reader.onload` function so, you can't call `get()` anywhere except this event function.

> Last but not least, bringing everything together how would I allow the
>   interface to FIRST allow the user to upload a CSV file and THEN when
>   it is uploaded, the interface will change to the Highcharts bar chart?
>   Is there some sort of code I need to write to do this?

Actually, I think the process of generating the chart should look like that:

1. Generate an empty chart (or with some initial data)
2. Get CSV from file
3. Parse CSV you've got
4. When parsed just update the chart with new `categories` and whole `series` object using `Chart.update()` method.

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update

**Live example with parsing data in correct way:** http://jsfiddle.net/db0vsgmh/